# Is there a way to hook rebuild permissions?

Tags: users

I'm working on a module that works with nodeaccess_userreference, I have to add some actions to the rebuild permissions function of the core.
Is it possibile?

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7, the submit handler for admin/reports/status/rebuild is [`node_configure_rebuild_confirm_submit`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.admin.inc/function/node_configure_rebuild_confirm_submit/7), which calls [`node_access_rebuild`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_access_rebuild/7).  Just note that `node_access_rebuild` can take a while (and why it support batch mode).

Comment: Yes, I think that in my module I'll have to add a function like rebuild permissions but that does something different.

Comment: What permissions do you need to rebuild?  That module implements hook_node_access() and siblings, and node_access_rebuild() rebuilds those tables.

Comment: My module extend nodeaccess_userreferences so, if I set a user_reference with this module, I "force", with hook_node_presave, that all users with the selected role are referenced to the node. So I can tell the system that "who has the role X can edit (or delete) nodes that have an authot that has the role X. But if I add a user with this role (or if I add this role to a user) I've to rebuild every node with this field. I would also add the possibility to do the same thing with users that are referenced, with node_reference, to the same node.